# How to implement a "Vulcan command" on iOs

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on an app where it might be desirable to have a "Vulcan command" available for certain functions.  What is the best way to implement this?

The obvious would be to have a view overlaid on top of the entire UI and use it to detect multi touch events.  If the touch is in the right places the command is triggered.

I also thought of the idea of placing invisible buttons in the corners of the UI and instructing the user to touch two, three or four corners to activate the function.  Can UIButton be used this way?  I can see setting up actions to trigger on touch down and then keeping track of which buttons are also pressed.  Haven't tried it yet.

Thanks,

-Martin

Comment: I imagine he means a long multi-touch gesture where the fingers are located in specific places. Like Spock doing a mind-meld.

Comment: Yup, you got it.  Maybe this isn't a term that is in common usage these days.  It was commonly used to describe having to press multiple keys on a keyboard to access a function, like Ctrl-Alt-Del on a PC.  Trekkie reference is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Specifically, a UILongPressGestureRecognizer set to recognize only multi-finger touches. You can even hit-test each of those touches and make sure they're within the target regions.

Comment: +1 `UIGestureRecognizer` is an embodiment of the platonic idea of Awesome.

Comment: @Dave - Totally. A couple weeks or so ago I'd never played with them. My client wanted to add "long touch to delete" behavior and I was rolling my eyes and sighing and worrying about how long it would take. With a gesture recognizer, it took about two hours. Beautiful!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of UIGestureRecognizer.  It does exactly what I need to accomplish.

Comment: OK, I just did that.  Thanks.